# Application crashes when I bind MainActivity to Launcher Intent

Tags: java, android, html

Below is the list of classes I have in my application.  I am trying to to make MainActivity to be the first to show but my app always starts from the Dashboard.  When I change it my app crashes.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Dashboard"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".Music"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".MusicVideo"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".Home"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".News"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


    <activity android:name=".Relationship"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>`
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Add the crash log. Maybe a theme related issue?

Comment: Make sure you clean and build the project. Note there is a backquote (`) after <intent-filter> that shouldn't be there.

Comment: please crash log and also clean and rebuild the project